# Re-render a usercontrol after removing it from a container

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, render, measure

I have `UserControl` which I display like this, it's for previewing a receipt ticket before printing:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="xzScroll" Template="{StaticResource scrollView}" Height="488" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <Border x:Name="xzPreview" BorderThickness="0" Background="White" Margin="0,0,10,0" Padding="15">
        // The UserControl
    </Border>
</ScrollViewer>
```

When the user wants to print the receipt, I remove the `UserControl` from its parent `Border`, and try to re-measure and re-arrange the control according to the printeable area:

```
public void Print()
{
    PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();

    this.Measure(new Size(dlg.PrintableAreaWidth, double.PositiveInfinity));
    this.Arrange(new Rect(this.DesiredSize));
    this.UpdateLayout();

    dlg.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight);

    ....
}
```

However, the `Height` and `Width` properties won't change, resulting in a faulty print with messed up margins and some text clipping on the sides.

When I create a new instance of my `UserControl` in code, and then use the `Measure` and `Arrange` methods, I see the `Width` and `Height` properties change according to the `PrinteableAreaWidth`, resulting in a proper receipt ticket.

How can I make sure the `Width` and `Height` properties are properly getting set?

Answer (score 0):

Is it right that you want to to resize the Usercontrol?

If yes, why don't create a Class (ViewModel) for the Usercontrol with the two Properties Height and Width and bind the User Control to these Properties.
Than you can change the size without removing the Usercontrol.

Here for Example how such a ViewModel could look like. You will need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class UserControlViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private double _height;
   private double _width;

  public double _height
  {
     get { return _height;}
     set {
           if(_height == value)
           return;

           _height = value;

           OnPropertyChanged();
          }

  public double _width
  {
     get { return _width;}
     set {
           if(_width == value)
           return;

           _width = value;

          OnPropertyChanged();
         }
```

And in Xaml you can bind it this way.

```
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="xzScroll" Template="{StaticResource scrollView}" Height="488" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
<Border x:Name="xzPreview" BorderThickness="0" Background="White" Margin="0,0,10,0" Padding="15">
   <MyUserControl 
 DataContext = "{Binding MyControlViewModelObject}"
Height = "{Binding Height}"
Width = "{Binding Width}"/>
       </Border>
  </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have declared the UI elements in your `UserControl` with exact `Margin` and/or `Height` and `Width` dimensions... of course, I can't be sure about that because you didn't show us your relevant code.

However, if this is the case, then you won't be able to rearrange them by re-sizing the `UserControl` externally. The solution is to use `Grid` controls to organise your UI elements, so that they can be automatically re-sized when the `UserControl` is resized. See the [`Grid` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for further information.

Comment: My `UserControl` only contains some `Grids`, `ItemControls`, `TextBlock` etc with no hard coded margins or width / heights. That's what it makes so odd, because if I render in code only without placing my `UserControl` in the `Border`, everything gets stretched really nicely. Any ideas?

Comment: Your `ScrollViewer` has an exact `Height` set, so that would stop the `UserControl` from re-sizing.

Comment: I removed all possible exact `Heights` and `Margins`. But unfortunately still no luck :(. Guess i'll just print the code-behind instance.